# laravel 11 Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Brand" not found

Tags: laravel, factory, laravel-seeder

Few hours ago, i fill my User table i had many error, but with help from here i corrected and User works good. Now i need to fill Brand table, it's strange i have exactly the same errors, i corrected except this one (same as before) but this time it doesn't word and i don't understand why whereas i checked many times i have more or less the same code etc
For information, i try without Factory and it works actually but i need to do it with factory same for User
here a picture
Thank you for your help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCsGL.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please do not put up pictures of code, code is text and belongs in a code block in your question ... having said that, your alias for `Authenticatable` is incorrect as it is aliased to what the error message is saying is missing instead of being an alias for something in the framework

Comment: hello, my english is not good so i thought its better for me to use images to make my self understand. By the way i didn't get what do i have to change in which page and for what for exemple replace this line by this one ? (because as i said my other table User is the same and works so i dont get it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your seeder, you are using Brand as the model which is correct, but your import in the brand model isn't correct as it's coming from the illuminate/auth package, where Brand isn't a thing. Importing it as authenticatable won't work because it doesn't exist. Unless you have a specific reason for using the authenticatable class on the brand model, you can delete that line as well as delete the extends authenticatable.  It works on your seeder because you are calling the Brand model without using the authenticatable.